# Nagios check_cert - CRITICAL - Cannot make SSL connection

Tags: ssl, nagios

I am using Nagios core at the moment to monitor the status of my domain and ssl cert. However, for one of my site, I can't get the expiry information of the SSL certificate. 
The error shown on Nagios is as below:

```
CRITICAL - Cannot make SSL connection
```

The check_cert settings for the site is as below:

//cert.cfg

```
define service {
        use                             generic-service
        host_name                       cert
        service_description             [cert] {mysite's domain info}
        check_command                   check_cert!{mysite's domain info}!-C 30,15
}
```

I am currently monitoring the domain status over Nagios for the same site as well, but it is working completely fine and there isn't any notice or error shown on Nagios.

Does anyone know why the domain connection is working whereas the ssl connection is not?

P.S. The OS that I used to monitor my site (the one that I installed Nagios) is CentOS 7.

Comment: Try with `curl -v --head https://your-domain.info`. Is it working?

Comment: @Rohlik Thanks for your help. I tried the curl command and it is still not working.I tried it in the format of `$USER1$/curl -v --head $ARG1$` where I specified `https://your-domain.info` in my define service. I am quite new to Nagios and I don't know if I am doing it correctly. Please correct me if I am doing anything stupid:(. Also, the original command that I used to check the ssl of my other sites is like this: `$USER1$/check_http -H $ARG1$ $ARG2$ $ARG3$ $ARG4$ $ARG5$` and it works fine for my other websites. Is there any other settings that I needed to check?

Comment: And are you sure, that your website is reachable via SSL/HTTPS?

Comment: @Rohlik Yeah I can access it through SSL/HTTPS, I am using let's encrypt at the moment. However, my other sites, which are also using let's encrypt, don't have any problems. I can also access to the domain information about {my site}, so I am a bit confused on why this is happening.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading through the nagios documentation, I figured out the reason why nagios wasn't able to make a SSL connection. Apparently, a hand-shake was needed prior the SSL-certification check, so without specifying the option. The following error appeared...
https://nagios-plugins.org/doc/man/check_http.html

```
CRITICAL - Cannot make SSL connection
```

In order to solve the problem, the `--sni` option is what I needed.

```
define service {
        use                             generic-service
        host_name                       cert
        service_description             [cert] {mysite's domain info}
        check_command                   check_cert!{mysite's domain info}!-C 30,15 --sni
}
```